# Building the aws-sdk-ios for osx

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sdk, aws-sdk

I am trying to build S3 Upload functionality onto a desktop application in OSX using the AWS SDK, and can't seem to get started.  I realise the AWS SDK is built for mobile only, but I downloaded a copy of amberdixon's version of the framework which I believe is compatible with the desktop environment.
https://github.com/amberdixon/aws-sdk-ios

Problem is I have no idea how to build it into the application. The readme states to "build the framework target", but I find myself in the position of not knowing exactly what that means and without further guidence in the readme I don't know how to proceed.

Believe me I have searched for potential clues to help, but without knowing exactly where to start I can't ask a more specific question so I apoligise for the remedial questions:

How do I add the ability to upload files to S3 from an OSX application?  How do I "Build the Framework target" What is the target? Trying to build the S3_Uploader sample fails with the error that the #import for AWSS3 header file is not found.
When I build the AWSiOSSDK.xcodeproj as specified in the readme I cant find the new framework directory in the top level directory as specified in the readme.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK - I think this is more of a question of not understanding xcode termonology as I am quite new to this IDE. 
Apparently xcode has an "Archive" function that releases the project, so 'archiving' the framework actually built it and produced a .framework file.